# Ant is using wrong java version

Tags: java, ant

I'm using Ant 1.7.0 and installed java 1.6 which is in JAVA_HOME.

I want to build a project using java 1.5, so I've exported JAVA_HOME to be my java 1.5 directory.

```
java -version
```

says "1.5".  When I run Ant it uses java 1.6.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You can write a batch script to specify exactly how to run it. If its just compiling, you could specify the version in the command, like: <javac target="1.5" srcdir=.../>

Comment: Take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743785/i-am-getting-wrong-java-version-on-running-ant-build/61190824#61190824) for wrong JAVA version

Answer (score 75):

Just had this issue, it happened because I'd first added the build file to the ant-view when the default JRE was 1.6.

There was no project-specific JRE and I changed the default to 1.5, even eclipse was running in 1.5, and JAVA_HOME was 1.5 too.  Running the ant target from the command line used JRE 1.5, but within eclipse it still used 1.6.

I had to right-click the ant target, select Run As... and change the JRE under the JRE tab.  This setting is remembered for subsequent runs.

Comment: I've just realised the question did not mention Eclipse at all.  My answer is for the described problem when using Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for ending a few hours of frustration.

Comment: if you are not using eclipse then check out my answer at the bottom.

Comment: I love how questions have many flavors of answers for the different environments and setup of our users.

Answer (score 34):

In Eclipse:

- Right click on your build.xml
- click "Run As", click on **"External Tool Configurations..."**
- Select tab **JRE**.  Select the JRE you are using.

Re-run the task, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 25):

According to the [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars), setting JAVA_HOME should work - are you sure the changed setting is visible to ant?

Alternatively, you could use the JAVACMD variable.

Comment: I have ths issue myself atm and JAVA_HOME is pointing to the right JDK, however ant is still reporting the wrong java version.

Comment: JAVACMD as a full path to executable java.exe worked for me (win 10)

Answer (score 20):

Run ant in verbose mode : `ant -v` and looks for clues.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I first tried building a project into a lib with jdk 1.8. I later discovered I needed to build it on 1.7 instead, so installed jdk 1.7, changed JAVA_HOME but still ant kept building it with 1.8. Using `ant -v` I discovered that ant was correctly using jdk1.7, yet the build was omitting all classes on the temporary folder because they were already there because of my previous attempt. So all I did was delete the temporary folder, and it recreated them, this time with jdk 1.7 like I wanted. Might help someone

Answer (score 17):

You can use the target and source properties on the javac tag to set a target runtime. The example below will compile any source code to target version 1.4 on any compiler that supports version 1.4 or later.

```
<javac compiler="classic" taskname="javac" includeAntRuntime="no" fork=" deprecation="true" target="1.4" source="1.4" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}">
```

Note: The 'srcdir' and 'destdir' are property values set else where in the build script,
e.g. `<property name="classes" value="c:/classes" />`

Answer (score 11):

You could achieve that with following steps, if you are using Eclipse IDE:

1. Right click on the task in your ant build file (`build.xml`).
2. Mouse over "Run As", click on "External Tool Configurations...".
3. Add followings to "Arguments":

   ```
   -Dant.build.javac.target=1.5 -Dant.build.javac.source=1.5
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Build file:

```
<target name="print-version"> 
   <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
   <echo>Java/JVM detail version: ${java.version}</echo> 
</target>
```

Output:

```
[echo] Java/JVM version: 1.5
[echo] Java/JVM detail version: 1.5.0_08
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also specify in a javac task what level of compatibility ( 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 ) you want to use, you can set the "source" and "target" level values, check the docs here :
[Javac task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Comment: To guarantee compatibility, also add the `-bootclasspath` option when compiling.

Answer (score 5):

This is rather an old question, but I will add my notes for future references.

I had a similar issue and fixed it by changing the order of the exports in the PATH variable.

For example I was using a method of concatenating strings to my PATH by doing (this is just an example):

```
$> export PATH='$PATH:'$JAVA_HOME
```

If my variable PATH already had a java in it, the last value would be meaningless, thus the order would matter. To solve this I started inverting it by adding my variable first, then adding the PATH.

Following this idea I inverted the order that ANT_HOME was being exported. Adding JAVA_HOME before ANT_HOME.

This could be just a coincidence, but it worked for me.

Comment: This happened to me too. I wasn't sure what entry was conflicting with JAVA_HOME but when I put it at the beginning of the PATH, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

`JAVACMD` is an Ant specific environment variable. Ant doc says:

> JAVACMD—full path of the Java executable. Use this to invoke a different JVM than JAVA_HOME/bin/java(.exe).

So, if your `java.exe` full path is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe`, create a new environment variable called `JAVACMD` and set its value to the mentioned path (including `\java.exe`). Note that you need to close and reopen your terminal (cmd, Powershell, etc) so the new environment variable takes effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using eclipse. Then you can change the ant java property directly on the file as mentioned here.

http://pissedoff-techie.blogspot.in/2014/09/ant-picks-up-incorrect-java-version.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the following 2 properties for `javac` tag:

```
fork="yes"  
executable="full-path-to-the-javac-you-want-to-use".
```

Explaination of the properties can be found [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you run Ant from eclipse, the eclipse will use jdk or jre that is configured in the class-path(build path).

Comment: Yes by default, but it can be configured for every ant file differently, so to check every one can be crucial...

Comment: To find out for sure what java version ant is using:`<echo message="Ant java version: ${ant.java.version}" />`

Comment: Learning about ${ant.java.version} was a great thing for me, thanks!

Comment: where would i put this in the build.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable with the required java version (in your case java 1.5), then in `build.xml` use `executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac"` inside `<javac></javac>` tag .

example:

```
<target name="java compiler" description="Compiles the java code">
    <javac executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac" srcdir="./src" 
        destdir="${build.dir}/classes"> 
    </javac> 
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Ant Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars), set `JAVACMD` environment variable to complete path to `java.exe` of the JRE version that you want to run Ant under.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Ant will considered the JRE as the workspace JRE version. You need to change according to your required version by following the below.

In Eclipse:

- Right click on your build.xml click "Run As", click on "External Tool
  Configurations..." Select tab JRE.
- Select the JRE you are using.
- Re-run the task, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If your build file does not already have it (some do, e.g. Apache Tomcat), you can add an `echoproperties` target to `build.xml`, e.g.

```
<target name="echoproperties">
    <echoproperties/>
</target>
```

Then you can run the ant task `echoproperties` and look for "java.version" or `ant -v` and look for "Java version", e.g. on my machine

```
ant echoproperties | grep java.version
```

shows

> [echoproperties] java.version=11.0.9.1

and

```
ant -v | grep -i "java version"
```

shows

> Detected Java version: 11 in: /opt/java/zulu11.43.55-ca-jdk11.0.9.1-linux_x64