# ant and jdk 1.6 but compile with 1.5

Tags: java, ant

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

in ant i need to compile with java 1.5. I try like this:

```
<javac destdir="${dest.dir}/${package.name}/${model.dir}/${output.dir}"
           classpathref="classpath"
           debug="${javac.debug}" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}" fork="true" verbose="${verbose}"
           deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" encoding="Cp1250" source="1.5"
           target="1.5" memoryinitialsize="1024m"
           memorymaximumsize="1024m">
```

but it looks like ant still compile with 1.6. Can i see which java ant use for compile? i get error of "Bad version number in .class file"

Comment: Which class file do you get the error for. Any chance this file is compiled by that task or might it be already compiled by a previous run without the `target="1.5"`? Or might it even be a library class?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i see which java ant use for
>   compile?

Try this:

```
<echo message="ant.java.version: ${ant.java.version}" />
```

Also read this thread for more help: [Ant is using wrong java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949678/ant-is-using-wrong-java-version)