# GWT packaging to war: Has Ant the wrong java version?

Tags: gwt, ant, packaging

I want to package my GWT 2.3 Application to a war file and deploy it on a weblogic server. I found this solution with ANT http://www.rubiconred.com/blog/build-package-a-gwt-app-to-war-using-ant/. But there is a Problem. The compile target throws an error and it looks to me like ANT is using the wrong Java version. But when I do Run As -> Ant Build... -> JRE The version is correct (1.6.0_11). So the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949678/ant-is-using-wrong-java-version) question did not work. And I am yet not so sure if the java version is the problem.

The console output looks like this:

```
Buildfile: C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\warbuilder.xml
prepare:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 124 source files to C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\build
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\dto\ApplicationDto.java:22: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
    [javac] import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\dto\UserDto.java:20: package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
    [javac] import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\ValidatorFactory.java:18: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validator;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\ValidatorFactory.java:36: cannot access javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
    [javac] class file for javax.validation.ValidatorFactory not found
    [javac] public class ValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\ValidatorFactory.java:71: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.ValidatorFactory
    [javac]     public interface GwtValidator extends Validator {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\activity\ApplicationAddPresenter.java:22: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\activity\ApplicationAddPresenter.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validator;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationAddViewImpl.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validation
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validation;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationEditViewImpl.java:25: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validation
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validation;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserAddViewImpl.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validation
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validation;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserEditViewImpl.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validation
    [javac] location: package javax.validation
    [javac] import javax.validation.Validation;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:23: package com.ibm.icu.text does not exist
    [javac] import com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\LogFileUtil.java:22: package org.apache.commons.lang.time does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\AutoinjectingRemoteServlet.java:19: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\AutoinjectingRemoteServlet.java:20: package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\AutoinjectingRemoteServlet.java:38: cannot access javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    [javac] class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found
    [javac] public class AutoinjectingRemoteServlet extends RemoteServiceServlet {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\AutoinjectingRemoteServlet.java:55: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletConfig
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.shared.AutoinjectingRemoteServlet
    [javac]     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\AutoinjectingRemoteServlet.java:55: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServletException
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.shared.AutoinjectingRemoteServlet
    [javac]     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\ValidationUtil.java:43: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.shared.ValidationUtil<T>
    [javac]     public String getErrorMessage(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\dto\ApplicationDto.java:46: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Pattern
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.shared.dto.ApplicationDto
    [javac]     @Pattern(regexp = "^(http|ftp|https){1}://.*$", message = "This is no correct url.")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\shared\dto\UserDto.java:47: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Pattern
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.shared.dto.UserDto
    [javac]     @Pattern(regexp = "^.+\\..+@roche.com$", message = "This is no roche email adresse.")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\ValidatorFactory.java:40: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\activity\ApplicationAddPresenter.java:118: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.activity.ApplicationAddPresenter
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\activity\ApplicationAddPresenter.java:119: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.activity.ApplicationAddPresenter
    [javac]         Set<ConstraintViolation<ApplicationDto>> violations = validator.validate(applicationDto);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationAddViewImpl.java:174: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationAddViewImpl.java:174: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Validation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationAddViewImpl.java:175: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Set<ConstraintViolation<ApplicationDto>> violations = validator.validateProperty(application, "url");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationEditViewImpl.java:182: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationEditViewImpl.java:182: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Validation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\ApplicationEditViewImpl.java:183: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.ApplicationEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Set<ConstraintViolation<ApplicationDto>> violations = validator.validateProperty(application, "url");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserAddViewImpl.java:149: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserAddViewImpl.java:149: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Validation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserAddViewImpl.java:150: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserAddViewImpl
    [javac]         Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDto>> violations = validator.validateProperty(user, "email");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserEditViewImpl.java:155: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Validator
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserEditViewImpl.java:155: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Validation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\client\view\UserEditViewImpl.java:156: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ConstraintViolation
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.client.view.UserEditViewImpl
    [javac]         Set<ConstraintViolation<UserDto>> violations = validator.validateProperty(user, "email");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:50: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGFILE_EXTENSION_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:50: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGFILE_EXTENSION_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:67: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGFILE_EXTENSION_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:67: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGFILE_EXTENSION_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:78: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGLINE_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:78: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGLINE_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:95: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGLINE_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\DateUtil.java:95: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.DateUtil
    [javac]         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(ServerProp.get().getProperty("LOGLINE_DATE_PATTERN"));
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\src\main\java\com\roche\research\logdashboard\server\domain\logparser\LogFileUtil.java:65: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable DateUtils
    [javac] location: class com.roche.research.logdashboard.server.domain.logparser.LogFileUtil
    [javac]                     || DateUtils.isSameDay(logFile.getDate(), since)) {
    [javac]                        ^

BUILD FAILED
C:\projects\logdashboard\LogDashboard\warbuilder.xml:31: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds
```

**So my question is:**

Is the Java version from ant the problem?

**Or:**

Is there an easier way to package the GWT application to a war file, then an ant script?
I tried some things, but nether did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Java version from ant the problem?

No.
It looks like you're missing dependencies from the classpath (specifically the Bean Validation API, ICU4j, Apache Commons Lang and the Servlet API).

> Is there an easier way to package the GWT application to a war file, then an ant script? I tried some things, but nether did work.

It depends how you build your project. If you're using Ant already, then use Ant to package your WAR; if you're using Maven, then use Maven; if you're using Make, then use Make; if you're using a shell script, then continue with it; etc.
If you don't have a build script and only rely on your IDE, then you have a more severe problem than packaging a WAR. But still, you can do that from within Eclipse (I know it can be done, I don't know how however).

Comment: I added the gwt-user.jar, gwt-dev.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar into the war/WEB-INF/lib folder and know the compile target works :) thx.

Comment: Er, ouch! **Do not ever put gwt-user or gwt-dev into WEB-INF/lib!** If you're using Apache Commons Lang and ICU4j on the server-side (which you do), then grab their JARs and put them there. And as you're using GWT-RPC, then put gwt-servlet.jar into WEB-INF/lib.