# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ibm/tivoli/si/build/util/MergeProperties : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to update the Maximo-Anywhere 7.5.2.1 release with the MaximoAnywhere4QRelease from the ISM Library.
I have followed the instructions given in the README file.
After running update-platform, got the build error
"patch-properties:
                     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ibm/tivoli/si/build/util/MergeProperties : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0".

Apparently this exception is caused by running the class files with the lower version of Java, than which is used to compile.
I am using java version "1.7.0_67".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your JAVA_HOME/PATH is pointing to the 1.7.0, it must be pointing to a Java 1.6 version.  We require 1.7 Java.

[Ant is using wrong java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949678/ant-is-using-wrong-java-version)

Comment: GenesisMobile:AnywherePlatform4QISMLib Mobility$ which java  
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Comment: GenesisMobile:AnywherePlatform4QISMLib Mobility$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Not everything failing,                                                                             install-anywhere-platform-only:
     [echo] Anywhere Platform installed successfully into all hybrid applications

patch-properties:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ibm/tivoli/si/build/util/MergeProperties : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0    
     [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: Very strange.  Can you add verbose to the line of the ant script that calls MergeProperties.  Maybe we can figure out where this older java is being picked up from.  It should be in build.xml around line 159.

Comment: [link to the build log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60daZYlrj8BZnJSNzBSZ1p2VTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Figured out the issue..I am switching the user before running the build.sh. JAVA_HOME is not set for the sudo. exporting the JAVA_HOME resolved the issue