# JavaFX - Application gives a lot of ant errors

Tags: java, javafx, ant, fxml

Today I created a JavaFX FXML project for fun but I got some errors right away, so I deleted the project and created a normal JavaFX project since that was what I originally needed. Now when I create normal JavaFX-projects, the folders and files and different than before. When I press the "Run Project"-button it runs as "jfxsa-run" and I get a lot of errors, but when I right-click and run the file it runs as "run-single" and I have no problems at all. 
When I run an old JavaFX-project it only runs as "run". How do I get it back as it used to be?

The error: http://piclair.com/wwesb (It's a picture)

Comment: The error says that there are classes which have been compiled with another incompatible version, so this JRE can’t use them

Comment: @michaeak But I'm creating applications as I am used to, but now it runs in two different ways and therefore creates some type of error. Just want it back as it used to be.
When I create a project it creates a dist folder and other files that I've never had before.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949678/ant-is-using-wrong-java-version